# GeoDjango heroku 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute 'spatial_aggregate_name'

Tags: python, django, heroku, postgis, geodjango

I'm trying to deploy my app on Heroku, which works locally but is throwing this error when deployed on heroku:

`AttributeError : 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute 'spatial_aggregate_name'`

For context I the api call that is triggering the error is trying to return all addresses from a table that are in a certain boundary.

my DATABASE settings in settings.py:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'map.apps.MapConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.postgres',
    'rest_framework',
    'django.contrib.gis',
    'coreapi',
    'listings',
    'drf_yasg',
]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'neighborhoods',
        'USER': 'django',
        'PASSWORD': db_pass,
        'HOST':'db_name.xxxxxxx.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT':'5432'
    }
}

# Heroku: Update database configurations from $DATABASE_URL.
import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

# Activate Django-Heroku.
django_heroku.settings(locals(), staticfiles=False)
```

I'm using the [heroku goe buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-geo-buildpack).

I just can't seem to figure out why it is working locally but not on heroku.

Here is my traceback:

```
> Django Version: 4.0.2 Python Version: 3.9.4 Installed Applications:
> ['map.apps.MapConfig',  'django.contrib.admin', 
> 'django.contrib.auth',  'django.contrib.contenttypes', 
> 'django.contrib.sessions',  'django.contrib.messages', 
> 'django.contrib.staticfiles',  'django.contrib.postgres', 
> 'rest_framework',  'django.contrib.gis',  'coreapi',  'listings', 
> 'drf_yasg'] Installed Middleware:
> ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 
> 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware', 
> 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
> 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
> 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
> 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
> 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
> 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
> 
> 
> 
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
> line 47, in inner
>     response = get_response(request)   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
> line 181, in _get_response
>     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py",
> line 54, in wrapped_view
>     return view_func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py",
> line 69, in view
>     return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py",
> line 509, in dispatch
>     response = self.handle_exception(exc)   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py",
> line 469, in handle_exception
>     self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py",
> line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
>     raise exc   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py",
> line 506, in dispatch
>     response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py",
> line 50, in handler
>     return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/app/listings/views.py", line 62, in GetHomesInHood
>     home_recs = find_homes(   File "/app/listings/HomeFinder.py", line 205, in find_homes
>     filtered_listings = filter_listings_model(hood_ids, beds, baths)   File "/app/listings/HomeFinder.py", line 40, in filter_listings_model
>     hood_boundaries = NeighborhoodBoundaries.objects.filter(pk__in=neighborhood_ids).aggregate(Collect('geometry'))
> File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py",
> line 403, in aggregate
>     return query.get_aggregation(self.db, kwargs)   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py",
> line 501, in get_aggregation
>     result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py",
> line 1189, in execute_sql
>     sql, params = self.as_sql()   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py",
> line 531, in as_sql
>     extra_select, order_by, group_by = self.pre_sql_setup()   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py",
> line 59, in pre_sql_setup
>     self.setup_query()   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py",
> line 50, in setup_query
>     self.select, self.klass_info, self.annotation_col_map = self.get_select()   File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py",
> line 267, in get_select
>     sql, params = self.compile(col)   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py",
> line 463, in compile
>     sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/aggregates.py",
> line 25, in as_sql
>     function=function or connection.ops.spatial_aggregate_name(self.name),
> 
> Exception Type: AttributeError at /listings/neighborhood/ Exception
> Value: 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute
> 'spatial_aggregate_name'
```

I just can't seem to pinpoint what is changing about the heroku setup and why it is not finding necessary attributes like 'spacial_aggregate_name'.  Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Maybe print yourself new database `DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)`, because it might update it wrongly.

Comment: @NixonSparrow Thanks for the suggestion.  When printing the database looks mostly corrrect but I do notice that 'CONN_MAX_AGE' = 0 but I set `db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)`.  So perhaps the update is not working.  Why wouldn't the update work?  how would i fix that?  Thanks ;)

Comment: Maybe try to simply set it like `DATABASES['default']['CONN_MAX_AGE'] = 500`. But for sure I cannot help you more than that. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

PostGIS is not enabled on Heroku Postgres databases by default. You need to enable it by running

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

on your database before you can use it.

See [the documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgis) for more details.

Comment: I have this extension setup in my database already.  The problem I think is that the heroku version is seemingly using a different database it initiates with heroku-postgres.

Comment: What do you mean by "seemingly using a different database it initiates with heroku-postgres"? Different from what? You'll need to enable this both on your development database, wherever it exists, and on the database Heroku provides. Have you don this _on the Heroku database?_

Answer (score 0):

This may be a patch rather than a solution, but I am able to get it to work if I make the following adjustments in settings.py.  Commenting out the following settings:

```
# Heroku: Update database configurations from $DATABASE_URL.
#import dj_database_url
# db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500, 
#                                      engine = 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
#                                     )
# DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)    

# Activate Django-Heroku.
# django_heroku.settings(locals(), staticfiles=False)
```

it seems these lines were changing the settings in heroku to use a different postgresql instance setup via [heroku-postgres](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql) instead of the database I already had setup properly.

Hopefully there is no need for those lines.

Comment: What is "the database you already had setup properly"? You're right, those lines configure Django to use a database that Heroku provides. Is that not what you wanted?